# Pagination url canonical problem

Tags: pagination, urls, rel-canonical

I have pagination link look like http://example.com/page/2 . The rel="canonical" is displayed like http://example.com/2.

How this can be fixed

Comment: How is the pagination implemented?

Comment: It's in a custom page template. with functions as  previous_posts_link().
Query: new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Does disabling all plugins helps? Particularly, SEO plugins.

Comment: can i use the above code for rank math as well? i also have pagination canonical issues with my blog pages like /2 and /3

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Yoast SEO and then add to functions.php:

```
function return_canon () {
$canon_page = get_pagenum_link(1);
return $canon_page;
}

function canon_paged() {
if (is_paged()) {
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'return_canon' );
}
}
add_filter('wpseo_head','canon_paged');
```